# html form to javascript and back to html

Tags: javascript, html

Please let me know why this doesn't work and how I can achieve this as simple as possible. my professor wants the simplicity to reflect 15 minutes or work. I just don't grasp it though. Thanks in advance!

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var obj = {
        name = "",
        address = "",
        ccNumber = "",
    }
    function printObj() {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = obj.name + " " + obj.address + " " + obj.ccNumber;
        }

    function storeInput(user_input1, user_input2, user_input3) {
        name = document.getElementById("myObject").form.user_input1;
        address = document.getElementById("myObject").form.user_input2;
        ccNumber = document.getElementById("myObject").form.user_input3;
    }

</script>
```

```
<form>
    <label><b>Enter full name</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input1">
</form>
<form>
    <label><b>Enter billing address</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input2">
</form>
<form>
    <label><b>Enter CC number</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input3">
</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="obj.storeInput(user_input1, user_input2, user_input3);obj.showInput()"><br />

<p id='display'></p>
```

Comment: What is your actual question ?

Comment: You have to specify your question. Otherwise, it will be hard for others to get it just out of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! You need your storeInput() to reference the declared object. Currently with your code as it is storeInput() is an independent function but for you event handler (onclick) to work. You need to redefine the storeInput() as

```
obj.storeInput() = function(user_input1, user_input2, user_input3) {.....};
```

Comment: Also your code does not show any use of **myObject** for the various lines in the ```obj.storeInput()``` function

Answer (score 0):

This will get the job done. It will not store the values, but will display them.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
     <form>
      <label><b>Enter full name</b></label>
       <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input1">
      <label><b>Enter billing address</b></label>
       <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input2">
      <label><b>Enter CC number</b></label>
       <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input3">
     </form>
       <input type="submit" onclick="aFunction();"><br />
    <p id='display'></p>

    <script>
    function aFunction(){
    var x = document.querySelector('#user_input1').value; // gets value of user_input1 field
    var y = document.querySelector('#user_input2').value; // gets value of user_input2 field
    var z = document.querySelector('#user_input3').value; // gets value of user_input3 field
    document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = x + ' ' + y + ' ' + z; // puts the values in <p> with id of 'display'
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps you understand.